# how do i get javascript dropdown to work in rails 6

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use semantic-ui in rails 6.1.7.3

javascript items are not working. On the console i get the error..

Started GET "/packs/js/application-0777f7a506acd75b1bfd.js" for ::1 at 2023-04-30 10:44:42 +0100

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/packs/js/application-0777f7a506acd75b1bfd.js"):

i created the packs folder and manifest.js manually and added the following

```
{
    "application.css": "/packs/css/application-b673e020.css",
    "application.js": "/packs/js/application-0777f7a506acd75b1bfd.js",
    "application.js.map": "/packs/js/application-0777f7a506acd75b1bfd.js.map",
    "entrypoints": {
    "application": {
    "css": [
    "/packs/css/application-b673e020.css"
    ],
    "js": [
    "/packs/js/application-0777f7a506acd75b1bfd.js"
    ],
    "js.map": [
    "/packs/js/application-0777f7a506acd75b1bfd.js.map"
    ]
    }
    }
    }
```

and applicaion.js has the following

```
import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
import "channels"
import '@doabit/semantic-ui-sass'

global.$ = require("jquery")
require("jquery") // Don't really need to require this...
require("jquery-ui")
require("jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui")

Rails.start()
Turbolinks.start()
ActiveStorage.start()

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
})
```

i have searched the web and watched various videos but can find the right answer